# Squaring an $n$ magic square

Tags: diophantine-equations, magic-square

Given the following square, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{matrix}\right]$$

How do you find the set of $\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the following condition:
$$a^n+b^n=c^n+d^n=a^n+c^n=b^n+d^n=c^n+b^n=a^n+d^n$$
where $n\geq2,\in\mathbb{N}$.

> Starting small, does a solution exist for $n=2$? Aside from *trial and error*, what method should I use to *even begin*?
>
> I am aware that you cannot construct a *magic square with only 4 terms*, but what if the terms were squared? cubed? Does such a limitation extend to all powers?

Comment: $a^n+b^n=a^n+c^n$ implies by subtracting $a^n$ from each side that $b^n=c^n$.  As we are working solely with natural numbers, this implies that $b=c$.  Similar implications can be seen by taking equations involving other pairs of expressions.

Comment: “What if the terms were squared?”. Then you would have a magic square with $\begin{bmatrix}a^2 & b^2\\c^2& d^2\end{bmatrix}$, of course, which you already know is impossible.  This variation is more impossible than the original :).

Answer (score 2):

I think it just has a trivial solution: $a=b=c=d$.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing.